# Is there a better method than Solution Folders for referenced DLLs in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

We've just switched from SVN to TFS 2013, and I'm trying to set up a new gated build.

The project I'm currently working on has a couple of "referenced assemblies": DLL's it's dependent on which are fixed in place and don't have a nuget reference. As soon as I tried to compile my new build, it failed complaining it couldn't find these DLLs.

I assumed the answer was to include them in the solution somewhere. Which is fine, except that using solution folders appears to be a flaky, error-prone and rather rubbish way to fix things, as per [Storing referenced Dlls in visual studio solution folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971807/storing-referenced-dlls-in-visual-studio-solution-folder)

However, that dates from 2011. Are there any better and more reliable ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't discount the nuget option so quickly :) If there is no publicly available nuget package available you can wrap your assemblies in your own nuget package using the nuget package explorer:
https://npe.codeplex.com
Does the fact that you mention nuget mean you're already using nuget for other references? If so mdkes sensd to stick with it. Also are these reference assemblies third party or built internally?