# How to add a Project (.csproj) to Solution (.sln) under a Solution Folder using dotnet CLI (command line)?

Tags: .net, .net-core, command-line, architecture, asp.net-core-cli

I am trying to add a csproj to a sln using `dotnet sln` command line.

Adding the project is easily achievable using the below command.

```
  dotnet sln todo.sln add todo-app/todo-app.csproj
```

But how do I add the same under a [Solution Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374081/what-is-a-solution-folder-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As of .NET Core 3 (preview, test with 3.0.100-preview7-X)

`dotnet sln solution.sln add --solution-folder foo1\foo2\foo3 bar.csproj`

It creates a nested hierarchy as of

```
solution.sln
|
└───foo1
│   │
│   └───foo2
│       │
│       └───foo3
│            │   bar
│            │   ...
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer here, OP asked to add project under a specific _solution folder_

Answer (score 50):

Please try below code to add project to a solution from projects sub folder

```
dotnet sln ../todo.sln add todo-app.csproj
```

Comment: tool tip of add a comment link says to avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 19):

Follow these steps:

1. `dotnet new sln --name "your solution name"`
2. `dotnet sln add "path of your .csproj file along with the name"`

Example:
If your name of the solution file would be "MyProject.sln" and the csproj is in same path then

1. `dotnet new sln --name MyProject.sln`
2. `dotnet sln add MyProject.csproj`

Comment: I like this answer because it omits the optional explicit providing of name of .sln file

Answer (score 11):

If you're using PowerShell or bash the below command is handy:

```
dotnet sln path_to_solution.sln add (ls -r **/*.csproj)
```

or simply:

```
dotnet sln add (ls -r **/*.csproj)
```

Comment: also try `$ dotnet sln add $(ls -r **/*.csproj)` when using zsh