# C# UnitTest hides "run,runall,debug,debug all"-Buttons, although test runs in console succesfully

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, xunit

As mentioned, I have to test some code and wanted to do it with xUnit. Then I have seen, that the buttons under the "[Fact]"-attribute are not shown, however. I use VS Code.

I searched for it and haave found absolutly nothing suitable. It s like the problem does not happens usually.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBKAe.png)

Here are my dependencies. I changed absolutely nothing. I just started a xUnit-project and the problem was presented.

If I test via "dotnet test" in the console, there is not problem, but it disturbs me.

I don t know what to tell more.. Would be very glad if someone could help me.

Thank U.

I just started a xUnit-project and the problem was just there. I changed absolutely nothing. In an other project the problem is not presented. It s just in this project. Don t know why.

Answer (score 0):

Thanksgod I found out what the problem was. I have a project, in which is no additional sln-File. There I have no problems.

**But**: In the current project my instructor added a sln-file additionally. So I did not know that someone has to add the project to the sln-file, after someone created it.

**Solution**: If there already exists a sln-file and you have created a new project, the current state is, that the new project is now included in the sln-file. The result is, that snippets, Attributes and so on will not be displayed. So you have to add the project to the sln file.

**Reference (how to add project to sln-file)**: [How to add a Project (.csproj) to Solution (.sln) under a Solution Folder using dotnet CLI (command line)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467914/how-to-add-a-project-csproj-to-solution-sln-under-a-solution-folder-using)