# How do you delete Solution Folder and contents within a VS extension?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I'm writing a VS Extension for VS 2017, and need to remove a Solution Folder and its contents from the solution.  I have been unable to find much documentation aside from using ProjectItem.Remove to remove items from a project and Project.Delete to remove a project from the solution.  However, calling each of these methods results in the following exception:

> The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG))

What is the proper way to delete Solution Folders in an extension?

Comment: Are you looking for this `IVsSolution7.CloseFolder` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution7.closefolder?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Comment: That method is similar to closing a solution; it doesn't actually change a solution or project.  I'm looking for a way to remove a Solution Folder and its files from a solution, which would in effect modify the sln file to remove the appropriate nodes.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up different concepts. A "solution folder" is a project like the others, but `proj.Delete()` doesn't work (as per documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.project.delete). You must use `dte.Solution.Remove(proj)`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Would you provide this as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Solution Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374081/what-is-a-solution-folder-in-visual-studio) is a project in a given solution like any other project.

To remove a project from a solution, you cannot call `proj.Delete()` which is [not implemented as per official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.project.delete?view=visualstudiosdk-2017):

> Removes the project from the current solution.
>
> Note that this method is not currently implemented.

Instead, you must must use `dte.Solution.Remove(proj);` and that should work for solution folders as well.